# terminal `node ./src/index.ts` SyntaxError

Tags: typescript, yargs

this my code

```
import * as yargs from 'yargs';

const newYargs = yargs.argv;

console.log(newYargs.value);
```

run the command in the terminal `node ./src/index.ts` i get this error

> import * as yargs from 'yargs': SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`node` does not understand TypeScript. It only understands JavaScript.

If you want to run TypeScript directly, use `ts-node`.

Comment: I installed locally ts-node.When I run ts-node `./src / index.ts ` I get an error              `ts-node: Unable to load file C: \ Users \ Rich ... ts-node.ps1, because script execution is disabled in
  this system`